# Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions thrown

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am working on an app currently in sandbox mode and I need to test out the posting of user's scores... When I try the following I get the above subject matter. The odd thing about this is that I have the been granting the said permission (using my personal user account). 
// var PERMS = 'user_likes,friends_likes,publish_stream,user_photos,photo_upload,publish_actions,offline_access';
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope='+PERMS+'&client_id='+APP_ID+'&redirect_uri='

I don't see the permissions in the Auth Dialog(I'm using the Enhanced Auth Dialog. They said its hidden :-S) but I am not "denying" any permissions and process the Auth Dialog successfully....

Can anyone tell me whats up here?

Comment: Posting the code example of how you're requesting the permissions may be helpful  :)  Thanks

Comment: Well there is a BUG...but the cause is actually the "Enhanced Auth Dialog". For some reason It doesn't capture/set/keep the "publish_actions" permission parameter. Disabling the "Enhanced Auth Dialog" app setting resolved the issue

P.S. There is ALSO another BUG where you CAN'T post scores for a "TEST User accounts". I was able to post scores to my personal account... but test dummy accounts...nada!

Comment: Post the bug links here after you submit them to Facebook, so other people who stumble across this can track them too :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you submitted a bug? If not you should, and I will vote on it as well. It is definitely a new bug. I can show my repro on it.

I just got this today as well. Within the last hour. Googled it, and found this post. Last week I successfully moved 5 apps to use timeline open graph, and the enhanced auth dialog. Today, moving a new app, I made sure to add publish_actions, added it to the code, uninstalled the app, and reinstalled it with the new dialog, and tried to run a timeline post. Got the same error. I don't get this error on the apps I moved last week, they work just fine (just tested). I also noticed a couple of other changes to the UI when editing in the dashboard. The preview windows are gone on the auth dialog page. You can still fill in the aggregations in the open graph section. My guess is they made some changes last week, and broke something with new app permission changes.